# How can I sort an embedded document?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

Is there any way to sort this document based on the contentItems?

I am rendering each content item like:

```
      {{#each contentItems}}
        {{> someTemplate}}
      {{/each}}
```

I want to render each one sorted by position on load. Is there any way to do this with an embedded document (contentItems) ?

```
{
    "_id" : "sYKXwp27o2MCBtPsN",
    "contentItems" : [
        {
            "_id" : "NwsWpu3dqj7jByLkq",
            "position" : 0.75,
            "title" : "Nested animations in AngularJS using ui-router"
        },
        {
            "_id" : "Rve9R5uJzvrbgfrrX",
            "title" : "AngularJS Data Models: $http VS $resource VS Restangular",
            "position" : 1
        },
        {
            "_id" : "BNq9Fe9gdYJ6Wgoym",
            "position" : 0.875,
            "title" : "Random title? Nope it's static."
        }
    ],
    "title" : "Some title"
}
```

To clarify: I want to be able to sort the contentItems by the position value, instead of sorting by the order of the documents themselves. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate over the result of a helper which sorts them. For example:

```html
{{#each sortedContentItems}}
  {{> someTemplate}}
{{/each}}
```

Where `sortedContentItems` looks like:

```js
Template.myTemplate.helpers({
  sortedContentItems: function() {
    return _.sortBy(this.contentItems, 'position');
  }
});
```

If you want the sort to be reversed you could do this:

```js
Template.myTemplate.helpers({
  sortedContentItems: function() {
    return _.sortBy(this.contentItems, function(ci) {
      return -ci.position;
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding a little to [David Weldon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25458175/1337856), this may be a good case to use a collection transform function. According to the Meteor docs:

> If you specify a transform option to the Collection or any of its retrieval methods, documents are passed through the transform function before being returned or passed to callbacks. This allows you to add methods or otherwise modify the contents of your collection from their database representation. You can also specify transform on a particular find, findOne, allow, or deny call.

So you could do the sorting in the helper that retrieves the document by passing a transform option in your `find` or `findOne` method. Like this:

```
{{#each sortedContentItems}}
  {{> someTemplate}}
{{/each}}
```

```js
Template.page.helpers({
  sortedContentItems: function () {
    var item = Items.findOne({}, {
      transform: function (doc) {
        doc.contentItems = _.sortBy(doc.contentItems, 'position');
        return doc;
      }
    });
    return item && item.contentItems;
  }
});
```

I wrote a [test in meteorpad](http://meteorpad.com/pad/hWngq6uCYZLmZfKsg) where you can see it in action.

Comment: Why use one method over the other?